# Symfony 2 multiple apps?

Tags: symfony

This appears to be the scariest topic relating to Symfony2, as after a week of searching and testing, I am still unable to find an answer to this.

In short, I am building an application that will have several subdomains, and I would like a different configuraton for all of them, while sharing multiple bundles from /src, and more importantly, import central config and routes (As well as each app's own)

I went down the road of creating individual /app directories, AppKernal.php files and bootstrap files. The main issue with this is detailed in another question, which has recieved no answers (not that I blame anyone TBH :D).
[Symfony2 multiple config and routing files for subdomain routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632702/symfony2-multiple-config-and-routing-files-for-subdomain-routing)

I have found discussion on the matter, Fabian even takes part in this:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/symfony-devs/yneojUuFiqw

And this discussion on a PR to github to provide support in version 2.2 (still 6mo away I hear)
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/3378

Is there anyone out there who has done this before? Is the process easy enough to explain? Is there any information available to assist with this?

I'm pretty much at the stage where it appears this simply is not possible. Which I find really strange for a system as touted as Symfony, especially when it appears Symfony1.4 did this rather easily.

**Update**

Thanks for your responses. The challenge is, there is a hierarchy of configs. These configs in turn import their own routing.yml files.

For instance: the domain http://testing.api.mydomain.com would include the following configs:

config_api.yml -> config_testing.yml -> config_dev.yml -> config.yml

All import their own routing.yml file. But only the one in config_api.yml is loaded. It seems framework: router: config option overrides previous usages in other config files, rather than extends.

In all fairness, the location of the app code is inconsequential. Having a hierarchical configuration with hierarchical routes seems to be the gotacha.

Cheers

Answer (score 12):

Multiple applications projects can be achieved by splitting your code in multiple Kernels.

You can then benefit:

- multiple web roots (useful for differents domains)
- shared & specific config (via imports)
- clean separation of Bundles...

I have described the whole process here: http://jolicode.com/blog/multiple-applications-with-symfony2 and you can find an example distribution here: https://github.com/damienalexandre/symfony-standard

Comment: this is amazing and funny tutorial! +10!

Answer (score 8):

I have looked into multiple application structure for Symfony2 as well. Since version 2.4, when routing supported [hostname based routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html), there has been no need for multiple apps.

All you now need to do is separate your "apps" into different bundles, say `AcmeSiteBundle` and `AcmeApiBundle`, then in `app/config/routing.yml`:

```
acme_site:
    host:     "www.{domain}"
    resource: "@AcmeSiteBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
    defaults:
        domain: "%domain%"
    requirements:
        domain: "%domain%"

acme_api:
    host:     "api.{domain}"
    resource: "@AcmeApiBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
    defaults:
        domain: "%domain%"
    requirements:
        domain: "%domain%"
```

Remember to have `domain` parameter set in `app/config/parameters.yml`

```
parameters:
    .....
    domain: example.com
```

Comment: Ah... glad I saw this comment. That looks pretty tidy. Great, thanks! +1

Answer (score 5):

You can create different configuration using the testing/Dev example :

***Step 1***
Create as many web/app.php file as you have subdomain.

```
web/app_subdomainx.php
```

***Step 2***
In each app_subdomain_X.php file change configuration :

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('subdomainx', false);
```

***Step 3***
create configuration file matching your environment

```
config_subdomainx.yml
security_subdomainx.yml
```

***Step 4***

acces you specific domain through

/web/app_subdomainx.php

**PS :**

Keep config.yml for common configuration (like db connection) and include config.yml into config_subdomainx.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }
```

Comment: not use envirionment for create multiple applications!!! http://jolicode.com/blog/multiple-applications-with-symfony2

Answer (score 0):

you can try to find something on github. I've found the following Bundle which should do this. [Imikay RouterBundle](https://github.com/imikay/RouterBundle)

Answer (score 0):

Basically Fabien is right, there's no reason to have more than one application, if you really have a need for a different application it's probably a different project. Bundles and libraries can be easily shared like any other bundle you see on the web.
Then you can have the small part of the set up belonging to each thing you call "app" in the app part of each project.
If they share the entirety of the code then it's just a matter of configuration hierarchy for each sub-domain, which could be your case considering you want to share some part of the config.

Symfony has many ways of allowing you to reutilise code which are very nice, but the framework is not meant to have many applications, if you want to try to hack it, go ahead, but then you're not using the framework anymore. And that's why you can't find examples, not because it's scary, it'd not be that hard to modify, it'd just be ugly, IMO.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The challenge is, there is a hierarchy of configs. These configs in turn import their own routing.yml files.

For instance: the domain http://testing.api.mydomain.com would include the following configs:

config_api.yml -> config_testing.yml -> config_dev.yml -> config.yml

All import their own routing.yml file. But only the one in config_api.yml is loaded. It seems framework: router: config option overrides previous usages in other config files, rather than extends.

Comment: I guess if you're actually sharing relative rroutes between different domains, what's most appropriate is having different projects, you can still hack environments to load different configs, you can see in your AppKernel you have the loader (there's a registerContainerConfiguration function) you can play with, and if you overwrite other stuff you can prevent other configs from being loaded. I don't personally recommend doing all this though... smells dodgy.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this bundle, that handle multiple domain website on same app and database:
https://github.com/AppVentus/MultiDomainBundle.